# Powershell: How to catch an Error correctly? ErrorAction -Stop vs. exit

Tags: powershell

When I want to stop a Powershell-Script when it runs into an error, how should I stop the script?

-ErrorAction -Stop ..

```
try {
     foo.bar
catch{
    $ErrorMsg = "An error occured during foo.bar"
    Write-Error -Message $ErrorMsg -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

or

```
try {
     foo.bar
catch{
    $ErrorMsg = "An error occured during foo.bar"
    Write-Error -Message $ErrorMsg
    exit
}
```

What is Best Practise and recommened?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `$ErrorActionPreference` to Stop beforehand, then call your script in the `try{}`. The script should use `throw` if it encounters an error that should terminate the script so it bubbles up to the calling script.

Something like

```
$oldErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try {
     foo.bar
}
catch{
    # re-throw the exception
    throw
}
finally {
    # reset the ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorAction
}
```